# Selenium DropDown Select With Auto Popup

Tags: selenium, dropdown

[image: Selenium DropDown Select With Auto Popup]

Hello,

Please check the Screen Attached.
I have tried selecting "Week End Day"= "Sunday" with all the given methods. But its selecting "Saturday" instead of "Sunday".

There are Auto Populated popups which can be made off/on. Even if I Off the Auto popups, the methods selects "Saturday" instead of "Sunday".

Please let me know If there are any Solution for that:

> Method1

```
selectDropDownValue("0_4", "Sunday");

public void selectDropDownValue(String object, String value) {
  driver.findElement(By.id("0_4")).sendKeys("Sunday");
  driver.findElement(By.id("0_4")).sendKeys(Keys.UP);
  driver.findElement(By.id("0_4")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
}
```

> Method2

```
driver.findElement(
  By.xpath("//div/select[starts-with(@name,'WK-END-DATE_')]")
).sendKeys("Sunday");
```

> Method3

```
driver.findElement(
  By.xpath("//div/select[starts-with(@name,'WK-END-DATE_')]")
).sendKeys("Sunday", Keys.TAB);
```

> Method4

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("0_4")));

dropdown.selectByValue("6");
```

Or:

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Sunday");
```

Comment: public void selectDropDownValue(){

    List<WebElement> options = getDriver().findElements(By.id("0_4"));

    for (WebElement option1 : options) {

    if("Sunday".equals(option1.getText().trim()))

     option1.click();
    
     WaitHelper.waitAdditional(2);
    }

Comment: String str="Sunday";

  driver.findElement(By.id("0_4")).click();

     for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){

     driver.findElement(By.id("0_4")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));

Comment: is it possible to give link to the url?

Comment: it Worked, i just copied the same code 2 times, for the values which starts with the same alphabet. Like

 driver.findElement(By.id("0_4")).sendKeys("Sunday");
 driver.findElement(By.id("0_4")).sendKeys("Sunday");